# VBA String to Formula

Tags: string, excel, formula, vba

Hi I have created a quick function that evaluate string

```
Function Evalue(ByVal str As String)
Application.Volatile
Evalue = Evaluate([str])
End Function
```

I have an array with all the formulas I use as string. Depending on the case I use INDEX/MATCH to choose the good formula then Evalue  to evaluate it.

If the string formula is in 1 block like SUM(A1:A20) it works perfectly
But if it is in several blocks like

`SUM(A1:A20)-SUM(B1:B20`)  it returns a `#NAME` error,  if I put the string in the array between `' '`  or `" "` it returns `#VALUE` error.

Comment: How about `(SUM(A1:A20)-SUM(B1:B20))`?

Comment: Still `#NAME` Error...

Comment: Oh, right.  probably take `[]` off `str` when calling Evaluate.  Checking now...

Comment: Did it Still `#NAME` Error... too bad for me

Comment: Is this in a module or in a worksheet? If the function is in a module it won't know what sheet you are referancing. I would try `Evaluate("=SUM(Sheet1!A1:A20)-SUM(Sheet1!B1:B20)")`

Comment: No it is in a worksheet

Comment: @ja72 Note: I put the same function in a module and called it just fine from within a sheet without specifying which sheet `A1` etc was in.  (with 1 fix)

Answer (score 2):

** snip ** The original code works just fine as written.

The cell I tested looked like this:

```
=Evalue("SUM(A1:A3)-SUM(B1:B3)")
```

Here's the security problem:

Apparently the **first time** you open and save a workbook, storing code in a module is enough to make it **accessible to be run** from within worksheet cells.  However, the **next time** you open the same worksheet (even if it is macro enabled) it's very much more difficult to get things working again.  Apparently the original code works fine as written.  However, Excel **hints it exists** and then reports a **#NAME error** when you try to use it.  There's a thread here with more info:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a79b7d8-178e-4cf5-8bc3-782a58b55a8b/vbaexcel-function-defined-by-user-gives-error-personalxlsb-weird?forum=isvvba

Apparently it requires installing an "add-in" to perform the simplest operation.  (Or you can use your personal.xlsb file)

Comment: `=Evalue("SUM(A1:A3)-SUM(B1:B3)")`  this formula with `" "` give a `#VALUE` error instead of `#NAME` error   If I run `=SUM(A1:A3)-SUM(B1:B3)` it works fine

Comment: @user2118020 Looks like a permissions issue, see edits above.